# Async / await, TAP and EAP

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient

I'm trying to move from async socket code which is a bit messy (`BeginSend`/`EndSend`, `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive` and lots of internal 'administration') to an async [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx). I'm pretty new to async/await, so please bear with me...

Assume the following code (irrelevant code stripped):

```
public async void StartReceive()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var stream = this.MyInternalTcpClient.GetStream();
        if (stream == null) return;

        var buffer = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
        var bytesread = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
        if (bytesread == 0)
        {
            if (Closed != null)
                Closed(this, new ClosedEventArgs());
            return;
        }

        var message = this.Encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesread);
        this.MyInternalStringBuilder.Append(message);
        // ... message processing here ...

        foreach (var p in parts) {
            //Raise event per message-"part"
            if (MessageReceived != null)
                MessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }
}
```

My class has an internal stringbuilder that gets appended to each time data is received (this is because messages can be split up in more than one receive 'event'). Then, when some conditions are met, the stringbuilder (the "running buffer") is processed and the message is split into message-"parts". For each "part" an event is raised. Many instances of this class can be running in the system.

My questions are:

1. Am I correct in assuming/understanding the `MyInternalStringBuilder.Append` is never called "out of order"? Each time the `TcpListener` receives data it will be added, "**in order**", to the (internal) stringbuilder? I don't need to use locks?
2. Since this `StartReceive` method uses an internal ("infinite") loop and raises events I don't see the point in making the StartReceive method `async`, but I have to (for obviously being able to use `await` at all). I know I'm mixing TAP/EAP but I have to for reasons not relevant to this question. However, it feels "dirty" since "`async` shouldn't be `void`" is what I gathered so far. Maybe there's a better way to solve this (except for moving to TAP alltogether)?

Comment: I suggest watching [Async in ASP.NET](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET) from channel9, it also covers a brief history of async in C# with AMP, EAP and TAP. it might be helpful to you

Comment: I will (as soon as I get home since I don't have audio here) but I should point out this code is running as a ("system") service, not in IIS and has nothing to do with ASP.NET (though I'm not sure the video is specifically about that, yet...)

Comment: It is specifically about ASP.NET but the general concept about async is the same, and I'm sure it will provide you with some value anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will be in order. Because you only have one active buffer posted*, then you process it before your post the next one, event order is deterministic (post->receive->process->post->receive...). There is no need for locking if you only use the SB in this loop as you described.

However, there are obviously big 'if's with regard to what happens in the `MessageReceived` event. Assuming you do the decent thing (eg. process and post a response), should be OK. If you attempt to receive more from the event all hell will break loose (eg. send a response and then wait for response to the response, that will be bad). If your processing is event driven state machine ('received message 'foo' in state 'bar, respond with 'spam' and change state to 'bam', return into loop wait for more events) then it normally should be OK. Obviously, is hard to give a verdict w/o code, is all base don your claims and in my understanding of what you understand by making that claims (that is OK, you seem to know what you're talking about).

The processing you describe is not the fastest possible (because incoming bytes have no room to buffer while you process current buffer) but achieving high throughput would be a lot more tricky, exactly because of the order issue(s) you hint at. Besides, if the traffic is request-response then it really doesn't matter much.

`posted buffer`: a buffer was presented to the network to fill it up. In .Net there are about 1 Million layers of abstraction between the stream operation and AFD/tcp.sys, but the concept applies pretty much the same.

Comment: The traffic is, indeed, request->response(->request->response... lather, rinse, repeat). It should be completely asynchronous; so a better way to describe it would be message->response(->message->response...) or message1->message2->message3->response where response *could* be a response to message2 but it won't matter when it is sent, *as long as it is sent sometime* (preferrably A.S.A.P.). I should point out that several (many) of these "clients" can be 'running' in the system; each having it's own "state-machine".

Comment: IF sender expects response fro message2 but goes ahead and sends message3 before geting the response, then is not request-response. Request-response is a protocol (message exchange pattern rather) where neither party cannot send until it's 'turn' (ie. sender **must** wait for response to msg2 before sending msg3). So you *could* get a better throughput in theory if you allow message3 to come and process *while* you are processing message2 and it's formulating/sending the response. But don't do it unless you have to. Pandora's box.

Comment: All "Sender" does is "yell" 'hey, did you know Foo?', 'hey, did you know Bar?', 'hey, look at FooBar!'. Sometimes the "Receiver" needs to send a message 'Cool, tell Foo is said hi!'. When "Sender" needs a response it will stop yelling and calmly await a response. So, if it sends a message "Hey, look at this banana, let me know what you think" it will wait and the server will "some time" reply "Cool, it's gone bad, chuck it" before the "Sender" on which "Sender" will act and resume yelling.

Comment: It's kind-of-a "chatty" system with state-machines on both ends where "Senders" are reporting events and "Receiver" can opt to tell "Senders" to sometimes act upon something that happened (even if that was some messages ago).

Comment: Obviously a shot in the dark here, since is all Banana Broadcasting based metaphor, but you should consider a separate channel for the "shouts" (ie. different TCP pipe, or even an UDP broadcast or multicast). I got burned in a prior life by similar problem due to the inherent priority inversion occurring when everything flows on one pipe...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control the "Senders". They just send stuff over one channel/pipe...

Answer (score 2):

Completing Remus' answer, you might want to ensure that `StartReceive` can only be called once, or you're going to have serious problems and locks will be needed.

Regarding the `void` return, I personally think that's one of the cases this is fine, "top-level" asynchronous methods starting with `Start` or `Begin`, correctly conveying the meaning that this is a fire-and-forget method. That said, if you have such a method, you probably want to redesign things.

To do this, I'll use a library such as TPL Dataflow, where different actions are represented as asynchronous blocks. In your case, there will be a "Read from socket block" → "Process block" → "Send response block", each one triggered asynchronously after the other, allowing you to continue reading while you're processing. By doing this, you won't have this big loop, and the `void` return won't exist anymore. Many things have to be changed though.

Comment: +1 obviously if concurrent calls attempt to run the loop all hell breaks loose. It would be impossible to recreate any originally sent message. It didn't even occur to me anyone would attempt something like that :)

Comment: It's not in the posted code, but there is a "`if _running` -> `throw`"-construct in the method that prevents "starting" it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in assuming/understanding the MyInternalStringBuilder.Append is never called "out of order"? Each time the TcpListener receives data it will be added, "in order", to the (internal) stringbuilder? I don't need to use locks?

That is correct. `async` code is naturally sequential though asynchronous. So, even though under the covers `StartReceive` keeps returning and resuming, it will not resume multiple times simultaneously.

> Since this StartReceive method uses an internal ("infinite") loop and raises events I don't see the point in making the StartReceive method async, but I have to (for obviously being able to use await at all). I know I'm mixing TAP/EAP but I have to for reasons not relevant to this question. However, it feels "dirty" since "async shouldn't be void" is what I gathered so far. Maybe there's a better way to solve this (except for moving to TAP alltogether)?

I'm not a big fan of `async void`. First off, I assume you have a top-level `try`/`catch` within `StartReceive` that will initiate a socket shutdown if any exception is observed (if not, then you need one). Personally, I would write it as an `async Task` method and consider exposing the `Task` as a property (if you have events all set up for error handling as well, then you don't need the `Task` property).

There is one other thing to watch out for; there are problems with the strict read-only/write-only loop that socket newbies often write: during the read-only portion, the reader cannot detect a half-open scenario; and during the write-only portion, there is a (tiny) chance of deadlock, particularly with a malicious client. Ideally, a socket should always have a read operation going (which you do), and it should also periodically be sending something (e.g., keepalives). I have a [sockets FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) that goes into more detail.

To fix this, I recommend that you add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to all `await`s, and post your EAP events to a `SynchronizationContext` captured in the constructor (using `new SynchronizationContext()` if there isn't one). Then you'll need another independent loop of some kind that either sends keepalive messages periodically (if the protocol allows for it), or terminates the socket if it hasn't read anything for a period of time.

Comment: "_First off, I assume you have a top-level try/catch within StartReceive that will initiate a socket shutdown if any exception is observed_" -> Left it out for clarity, but it's "around"/"wrapping" the loop (e.g. `try { internal-loop } catch {}`. Thanks for the FAQ and other interesting observations; the protocol doesn't support "keep-alives" (or a 'hearbeat') which kinda sucks indeed, I would need to keep track of an internal timer/timeout of some kind to kill "inactive" connections...

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to use locks if you share the StringBuilder between multiple threads.

Also, I don't understand what you mean by *in order*. `Append` will be called in *an* order. It may not be the order you want, but then there is nothing in this code that ensures any particular order.

I can say that the calls to `Append` *inside* that method will be called in the order the code executes them, which should behave exactly like you expect from the code, but again, if multiple threads call this at the same time, the order between the threads is not given.

As for your second question, why not simply write the whole thing without using the `async` keyword, and calling it in a task or a thread instead?

Comment: The idea is that for each "client" an instance of my class is instantiated. By "in order" I mean, the order in which the data is received by the TcpClient (assuming the TcpClient handles out-of-order TCP packets and such, which it does).

As for calling this in a task/thread: that sounds like an idea... Won't I run out of threads where "await" will more efficiently shedule different awaits?

Comment: Yes, but then you will still have the code as it is. To be honest, there's nothing wrong with the way the code is structured now, but personally I don't like fire-and-forget methods where you don't have a way to wait for them to finish or cancel them.

Comment: I can finish/cancel by closing the TcpClient which will will trigger the `if (bytesread == 0)` -> `return` which will "break" the infinite loop.